# Calculate correlation for discrete-like values from two columns of DataFrame in Pandas

Tags: correlation, python, pandas

Here's the code snippet:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data=[1,1,2,2,3,3,3], columns =list('A'))

def m(x):
    if x == 1:
        return 2
    if x == 2:
        return 3
    if x == 3:
        return 1
    return -1
df['B'] = df['A'].map(m)
print df.head(n=10)

   A  B
0  1  2
1  1  2
2  2  3
3  2  3
4  3  1
5  3  1
6  3  1
```

As we can see, column B is created by mapping value from column A, thus they should have correlation of value 1, but what I got from below is all not satisfying. Could anyone give me some idea on how to calculate correlation of discrete data for two columns? Great thanks!

```
df['A'].cov(df['B'])
-0.47619047619047611
df['A'].corr(df['B'], method='spearman')
-0.68000000000000016
df['A'].corr(df['B'], method='kendall')
-0.50000000000000011
df['A'].corr(df['B'])
-0.58823529411764708
```

Comment: The question doesn't appear to be about statistics unless you read it. As you can see in the answer - fortunately posted before closing - the problem is about statistical misunderstanding, not about coding. It should be reopened.

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing wrong in your calculation. However, your mapping is not linear and therefore correlation between your variables is not 1 nor -1.

I suggest trying mapping 3 to 4 instead of 1 and compute correlation again. Then you should get correlation = 1.

For a different test, mapping 1 to 3, 2 to 2 and 3 to 1 should produce correlation = -1.

And please notice that correlation is just a measure on how much the variables are linearly related. If they are related by a deterministic mapping but that mapping is not linear, correlation will be low.

Comment: The point is that there's could be scenario with A->B, B->C and C->A, which I intend to dig out the correlation without having to change it manually since I can't see the correlation beforehand.

Comment: It's easy to prove that if  A->B, B->C and C->A is a linear relation, A=B=C. Or equivalently, if A->B, B->C and C->A correlation is not 1 nor -1. If you just want to compute the correlation, you already know how to do it with Pandas - you already did. Then, I don't see what is the problem.